# Nodemailer, works fine locally but doesn't work on my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

So I got this problem with my portfolio website, I'm new to nodejs and I wanted to make an email form so people visiting my website can get in contact with me. It works great when I run it locally on my mac but as soon as I put it on my server I get this error `{"message":"Something went wrong","error":{"code":"EAUTH","response":"535 Authentication Failed","responseCode":535,"command":"AUTH PLAIN"}}`

Her is how my code looks like this

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(express.static('public'));

// POST route from contact form
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
  let mailOpts, smtpTrans;
  smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.MAIL,
        pass: process.env.PASS
    }
  });
  mailOpts = {
    from: process.env.MAIL,
    to: process.env.MAIL,
    subject: 'Nytt mail från ' + req.body.name,
    text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email}) :
    ${req.body.message}`
  };
  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'Something went wrong', error });
    }
    else {
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success' });
    }
  });
});
app.listen(3000, () => {console.log('server is on, 3000')});
```

Comment: `process.env.PASS` is probably wrong.

Comment: make sure you setup the ENV variables for this environment as well

Comment: 535 is an incorrect authorization. Make sure your credentials are right.

Comment: @slaks I have set that up already. Just like I have done locally.

Comment: I found the problem.... Just like @Mattpengelly said apparently the environment is setup wrong so my server.js can't get the password and email from the .env file

Comment: make sure you answer the question below and mark your answer correct so the next person coming here will see it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Environment variables for this environment, for a server you'll need to setup a .bash_profile or some other form of setting ENV vars.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, apparently the variable name "MAIL" was already taken when I console.log(process.env) therefore I renamed it to EMAIL and now it works.